# Convert Await.result into for/yield

Tags: scala

I'm looking for a way to turn the following into a non-blocking call:

```
val (greeting, name) = 
    if (someCondition) { 
        ("Welcome", Option(""))
    } else { 
        var name = Await.result(userClient.getName(arg), Duration.Inf)) 
        ("Hi", name)
    }
```

I'm thinking of doing something along the lines of:

```
val (greeting, name) = 
    if (someCondition) { 
        ("Welcome", Option(""))
    } else { 
        for {
            name <- userClient.getName(arg)
        }
        yield {
            ("Hi", name) 
        }   
    }
```

The issue I'm facing is that the for/yield returns a Future[String] to the name tuple for else statement, but returns a Option[String] for the if statement.  I need them both to return an Option. In other words, I need to resolve the future. If I pull the name out of the yield, then it won't be in the same scope and the compiler can't figure out that there's a name in the for.

If this can be done without a for/yield that's okay. Just don't want it to be a blocking call.

Comment: How is your first example non-blocking? Doesn't awaiting count as blocking? For this to not block, you have to return a `Future`.

Comment: @Alec, I think the question has been worded rather misleadingly. The OP means the first call is blocking and they are trying to make it non-blocking.

Comment: @jrook Sure, but the second part of my comment is really the key: if they want it to be non-blocking, it has to return a `Future`.

Comment: @Alec jrook is correct. I have changed the wording a bit. Hopefully that clears up the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is

```
val (greeting, name): (String, Future[Option[String]]) = if (someCondition) { 
  ("Welcome", Future.successful(Some("")))
} else {
  ("Hi", userClient.getName(arg))
}
```

You can't convert a `Future[Option[String]]` into `Option[Future[String]]` without awaiting the `Future`; an `Option[Future[String]]` knows upfront if it is `Some` or `None` while `Future[Option[String]]` doesn't.

In this case, there is no need for a `for` comprehension.